# Non-Custom UITableViewCell causes textfield and textview to change when cells are reused?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having issues with my `UITextField` and `UITextView` when the cells are being reused, i.e. when I scroll pass the 2 cells containing a `UITextField` and `UITextView`.

I have seen many questions on SO regarding issues with reusable cells, but unlike those questions, I am not using a custom `UITableViewCell` because I have 5 prototype cells and each cell contains different properties, so creating 5 different custom `UITableViewCells` is not ideal for me.

I am creating my `UITextField` and `UITextView` programmatically within `cellForRowAt` like so:

```
extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()

        if indexPath.section == 0
        {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsCell", for: indexPath)

            let textField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: cell.frame.size.height) )

            textField.tag = 1

            if segueToThisVC == true && title.isEmpty == true
            {
                textField.text = "Required..."
            }
            else
            {
                textField.text = title
            }

            textField.delegate = self
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
            textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainViewController.textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)

            cell.addSubview(textField)
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 1 || indexPath.section == 2
        {
            let toolBar = UIToolbar()
            toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
            toolBar.frame.size.height = 35
            toolBar.isTranslucent = true

            let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(MainViewController.dismissKeyboard(_:) ) )

            let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

            toolBar.setItems([spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
            toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            if indexPath.section == 1
            {
                doneButton.tag = 1

                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsCell", for: indexPath)

                let textView: UITextView = UITextView()
                textView.tag = 2
                textView.textColor = UIColor.black
                textView.isScrollEnabled = false

                if segueToThisVC== true && description.isEmpty == true
                {
                    textView.text = "Optional..."
                }
                else
                {
                    textView.text = description
                }

                textView.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
                textView.delegate = self             

                cell.contentView.addSubview(textView)

                textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

                // Programmatically set the constraints of the text field
            }
            else if indexPath.section == 2
            {
                ...
            }
        }

        ...

        return cell
    }
}
```

My `UITextFieldDelegate` and `UITextViewDelegate`:

```
extension MainViewController: UITextFieldDelegate
{
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        textField.text = nil
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        if textField.text?.isEmpty == true
        {
            textField.text = "Required..."
        }

        if textField.tag == 1
        {
            if let textFieldTitle = textField.text
            {
                if textFieldTitle == "Required..."
                {
                    textFieldTitle = ""
                }
                else
                {
                    title = textFieldTitle 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField)
    {
        if textField.tag == 1
        {
            title = textField.text!
        }
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UIextViewDelegate
{
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
    {
        textView.text = nil
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
    {
        if textView.text?.isEmpty == true
        {
            textView.text = "Optional..."
        }
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)
    {
        if let textViewDescription = textView.text
        {
            description = textViewDescription 
        }

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

When `MainViewController` is initially loaded, the `UITextField`'s text is set to **Required** and the `UITextView`'s text is set to **Optional**.

If I don't scroll up to the point where the first cell (with `UITextField`) and second cell (with `UITextView`) become invisible, selecting the `UITextField` causes the delegate to call `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and selecting the `UITextView` causes its delegate to call `textViewDidBeginEditing`. This occurs as expected.

This is how the keyboard appears on both cells before scrolling, as coded:

[image] [image]

However, here are the issues I'm currently facing:

1. Scrolling the `UITableView` up past the first and second cell causes the `UITextView` delegate to call `textFieldDidBeginEditing` instead of `textViewDidBeginEditing`, triggering the keyboard meant for the `UITextField`
2. When the first and second cells are reused again, selecting the `UITextView` does not cause the **Optional** placeholder text to disappear, which is also caused by issue 1, therefore entering text into the `UITextView` shows the following screenshot:

[image]

3. Any text entered into the `UITextView` upon scrolling up past the first two cells causes the text to be displayed in the `UITextField` and the text disappears from the `UITextView` leaving the **Optional** placeholder text displayed instead. This occurs upon the two cells being visible again.

Since I am not using a custom `UITableViewCell`, I cannot use `prepareForReuse` so what I've tried to do was set the `UITextField` and `UITextView` text to nil in `didEndDisplaying` as shown:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    print("didEndDisplaying")

    // Dequeue the cell to load data
    var cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()

    if indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 1
    {
         cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailsCell", for: indexPath)

        if indexPath.section == 0
        {
            if let textField = cell.viewWithTag(1) as? UITextField
            {
                textField.text = nil
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if let textView = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UITextView
            {
                textView.text = nil
            }
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

However, this did not work. Can someone tell me what the proper what the proper way to reuse cells, considering `my code implementation`?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to link your table view to a model, or if you're making a form, try Eureka

Comment: You are always adding the text fields etc after you dequeue the cell.  When the cell is reused then you will add a second; you should use custom cell subclasses and initialise the fields in the cell subclass

Comment: @Paulw11 so the best option for me is to create custom cell classes for each one of my cells?

Comment: Yes, that will make it much easier for you to manage your cells and access the various text fields etc

Comment: @Paulw11..thanks..2 things: `1`: is creating custom cells for each and dequeing it faster than what I currently have or is performance not really affected, based on my current implementation? `2`: With the custom cells, do I need to worry about managing the reusable cells (cells not visible on screen) like I currently do?